# How to handle services for Android older than O?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-service

Is the following the correct way to create a service for Android version O and newer, as well as handle older versions? For O and newer I'd like to create a foreground service. For older versions, I assume a regular service needs to be created? Is the following code correct to handle this or is there a better way?

```
MainActivity.kt

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        Intent(this, ForegroundService::class.java).also { intent ->
            if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                startForegroundService(intent)
            } else {
                startService(intent)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
ForegroundService.kt

class ForegroundService : Service() {
    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            val channel = NotificationChannel("channel_service", "Foreground Service Channel", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT)
            channel.lightColor = Color.BLUE
            channel.lockscreenVisibility = Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC

            val service = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
            service.createNotificationChannel(channel)

            val notification: Notification = Notification.Builder(this, "channel_service")
                    .setContentTitle("Title")
                    .setContentText("Text")
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.fancy_small_icon)
                    .build()

            startForeground(1, notification)
        } 

        /**
         * Do work
         */

        stopSelf()

        return START_STICKY
    }

    override fun onBind(intent: Intent): IBinder? {
        return null
    }
}
```

Comment: "For older versions, I assume a regular service needs to be created?" -- you can use a foreground service there too. However, it would not appear that you need a service here. Why are you creating a service?

Comment: @CommonsWare, how are foreground services started on older versions? Do you build a notification with `NotificationCompat` or something?

Comment: "how are foreground services started on older versions? Do you build a notification with NotificationCompat or something?" -- using the same code that you have now, except that you call `startService()` (and you will not need the channel). That being said, I recommend using `NotificationCompat.Builder`.

Comment: Thanks @CommonsWare! Looks like `ContextCompat.startForegroundService()` handles starting the correct service. I've modified the code to use `NotificationCompat.Builder` for < O. I haven't tested well, but appears to be working.